# Travis CI build failed - (Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, travis-ci

I had Travis CI setup for CICD of my Angular Project. I have been using this seamlessly since 2 months now. Having no trouble. But since 2 days my builds are continuously failing and I'm not able to figure out the exact cause from the Build Log.

I have changed nothing that should cause this error. I've just made some Typescript and HTML changes and not installed any new packages or changed anything on my AWS end.

LOG :

```
Deploying application
uploading "04.0284d042a6c29213aaa1.png" with {:content_type=>"image/png", :acl=>"public-read"}
uploading "Roboto-Bold.dc81817def276b4f2139.woff" with {:content_type=>"font/woff", :acl=>"public-read"}
uploading "arrow_left.270f72df47e036d9cfa1.svg" with {:content_type=>"image/svg+xml", :acl=>"public-read"}
uploading "fa-solid-900.1709a2810c3752483683.ttf" with {:content_type=>"font/ttf", :acl=>"public-read"}
uploading "Roboto-Regular.2751ee43015f9884c364.woff2" with {:content_type=>"font/woff2", :acl=>"public-read"}
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_sse_cpk.rb:19:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_dualstack.rb:24:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_accelerate.rb:34:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.394/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-resources/services/s3/file_uploader.rb:42:in `block in put_object'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-resources/services/s3/file_uploader.rb:49:in `open_file'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-resources/services/s3/file_uploader.rb:41:in `put_object'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-resources/services/s3/file_uploader.rb:34:in `upload'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.394/lib/aws-sdk-resources/services/s3/object.rb:252:in `upload_file'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-s3-1.10.13/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in upload_multithreaded'
failed to deploy
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue today. What is the region you are using?

Comment: I'm using us-east-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you may be hitting [this issue](https://travis-ci.community/t/deploy-fails-with-aws-signaturedoesnotmatch/5835/2) with Travis' deploy system. We hit this same issue several days ago, after many months of smooth deployments.

We have an `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` value, which is encrypted for our build, and our YAML config in the `deploy` section looked like this:

```
    access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    secret_access_key:
      secure: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

The linked issue mentions:

> You are using the plain text value in the secure value. We rolled out additional changes to data processing so that we can prevent accidental exposures of these secrets.
>
> Your configuration was working before because we were passing through values when the decrpytion fails in such a case.
>
> Please try changing this configuration to:
>
> `secret_acces_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY`

Based on this, we changed our config to the following:

```
    access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

This fixed the issue for us.

Comment: Thank you so much!
That fixed it.